How to make storm trigger fn Zabbix
I have a system to put value of item by key every hour from outside by using zabbix_sender
how to define tigger at storm as you view at image?
Zabbix_Sender transfers values - if have a storm during the previous hour - send email
Value send to zabbix vith timestamp. Simple send at storm:
root@sens:/var/log/zabbix# cat /var/tmp/toZabbix/07-06-24/toZabbix_2024-06-07-14.txt |grep DPC_165
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758008 8
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758008 13
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758018 10
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758018 14
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758028 10
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758028 11
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758038 10
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758038 10
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758048 9
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758048 12
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758058 8
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758058 15
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758068 6
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758068 13
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758078 7
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758078 14
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758088 7
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758088 14
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758098 6
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758098 13
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758108 20
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758108 25
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758118 40
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758118 46
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758128 58
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758128 64
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758138 19
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758138 30
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758148 6
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758148 16
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758158 7
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758158 17
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758168 7
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758168 16
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758178 7
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758178 10
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758188 7
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758188 9
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758198 9
Switch3000 DPC_165out 1717758198 12
Switch3000 DPC_165in 1717758208 9
Storm1.img
Storm2.img
